# How to display many_many objects in page template in Silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

Our site has an object called "TrailNotice" which has a many_many relationship with the page type "TrailSection".

```
class TrailNotice extends DataObject {

  private static $many_many = array(
    'TrailSections' => 'TrailSection'
  );
```

This allows a single TrailNotice to be applied across multiple TrailSections via checkboxes in the CMS:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new CheckboxSetField('TrailSections', 'Applies to which trail sections?', DataObject::get('TrailSection')->map('ID', 'Title')));
```

How do I display the TrailNotices attached to a TrailSection in the TrailSection page controller?

I started with the following code:

```
class TrailSection_Controller extends Page_Controller {

  public function TrailNotices(){
    $TrailNotices = DataObject::get('TrailNotice');
    return $TrailNotices;
  }
```

But this will get all TrailNotice objects. How do I filter them so only TrailNotices attached to the TrailSection are displayed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define a many_many on both ways, then you can access it from both sides. One side has a `$many_many`

```
class TrailNotice extends DataObject {

  private static $many_many = array(
    'TrailSections' => 'TrailSection'
  );
```

on the other side you have to define `$belongs_many_many`

```
class TrailSection extends DataObject {

  private static $belongs_many_many = array(
    'TrailNotices' => 'TrailNotice'
  );
```

Then in your template you can just call the relation list and loop over it:

```
<% loop $TrailNotices %>
    $Title
<% end_loop %>
```

See [image: infographic] for all possible relations (thanks to @nightjar for providing the graphics).

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement a $belongs_many_many into your TrailSection model, something like that:

```
class TrailSection extends DataObject {

  private static $belongs_many_many = array(
    'TrailNotices' => 'TrailNotice'
  );

}
```

Then you can simply loop over $TrailNotices into TrailSection.ss template, without doing anything into your controller:

```
<% loop $TrailNotices %>
    $Title<br>
<% end_loop %>
```

You can check the Mentor sample in Stephen's link [Dataobject Relationship Management](http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/tutorials/dataobject_relationship_management/)

Answer (score 0):

SilverStripe stores many_many relations [RelationList](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-RelationList.html) that can be access on the object using `$this->RelationName()` (in this case `$this->data()->TrailNotices()`). The RelationList is a subclass of [DataList](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataList.html) so you can treat it a lot like a `DataObject::get()` for filtering the list.

```
class TrailSection_Controller extends Page_Controller {

  public function TrailNotices(){
    $TrailNotices = $this->data()->TrailNotices();
    return $TrailNotices;
  }
```

There is more information about SilverStripe's ORM and DataObject Relations in the help section [Dataobject Relationship Management](http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/tutorials/dataobject_relationship_management/) and (newer content) [SilverStripe Lessons](http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons)